# Value not returned for "eq()"?

Tags: jquery, html

I am writing a code for table, where I have 2 TDs in each row.

I am able to return first TD value having class "nameText" using eq(), but why the value of 2nd TD having class "codeText" not returned?

**here is the code:**

**HTML:**

```
<tbody id="expTableValues">
<tr class="no-border">
<td class="nameText"><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxItem">Director</td>
<td class="text-center codeText">Balkar</td>
<td class="text-right"><a class="mouseOverTooltip rowIcon color-amber deleteCenter"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Delete"></i></a><a href="#" class="rowIcon editCenter"><i class="fas fa-file-signature" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit"></i></a></td>
</tr>
```

**Jquery:**

```
var nameText = $(this).closest('td').eq(0).text();
var codeText = $(this).closest('td').eq(1).text();

alert(nameText);
alert(codeText);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have to point to the closest commont parent **`.closest('tr')`** before traversing back down the tree:

```
var codeText = $(this).closest('td').eq(1).text();
```

```js
$(".checkBoxItem").on("change", function() {
  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var nameText = $tr.find('td').eq(0).text();
  var codeText = $tr.find('td').eq(1).text();
  console.log(nameText);
  console.log(codeText);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="expTableValues">
    <tr class="no-border">
      <td class="nameText"><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxItem">Director</label></td>
      <td class="text-center codeText">Balkar</td>
      <td class="text-right"><a class="mouseOverTooltip rowIcon color-amber deleteCenter"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Delete"></i></a><a href="#" class="rowIcon editCenter"><i class="fas fa-file-signature" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Also, since you already  use **classes** `nameText` and `codeText`, even better, reference them:

```
var codeText = $(this).closest('td').eq(1).text();
```

```js
$(".checkBoxItem").on("change", function() {
  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr')
  var nameText = $tr.find('.nameText').text();
  var codeText = $tr.find('.codeText').text();
  console.log(nameText);
  console.log(codeText);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="expTableValues">
    <tr class="no-border">
      <td class="nameText"><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxItem">Director</label></td>
      <td class="text-center codeText">Balkar</td>
      <td class="text-right"><a class="mouseOverTooltip rowIcon color-amber deleteCenter"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Delete"></i></a><a href="#" class="rowIcon editCenter"><i class="fas fa-file-signature" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Won't `$(this).closest` resolve to a jQuery object that wraps only a *single* element, the matching `.closest` of `this`?

Comment: sorry, I have 3 TDs, so its my mistake earlier, now I edited, even this not work.

Comment: @delonixLover fixed my bugs :D

Answer (score 0):

Your [`eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) position is invalid you were using 2 as selector and you don't have any text inside that.

```
 $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
```

this will find the closest tr and find the td with index, remember it starts with 0. Checkout demo here I have implemented it on edit click, you can implement it as per your need.

```js
$(".editCenter").click(function() {    
  var nameText = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
  var codeText = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();

  alert(nameText);
  alert(codeText);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody id="expTableValues">
  <tr class="no-border">
    <td class="nameText"><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxItem">Director</td>
    <td class="text-center codeText">Balkar</td>
    <td class="text-right"><a class="mouseOverTooltip rowIcon color-amber deleteCenter"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Delete">delete</i></a><a href="#" class="rowIcon editCenter"><i class="fas fa-file-signature" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit">edit</i></a></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```